# what does the parameter 's' mean in the 'predict' function?

Tags: r

I've recently run a code which is:

```
glmnet.fit <- with(training.df, glmnet(poly(X, degree = 10), Y))
lambdas <- glmnet.fit$lambda
performance <- data.frame()
for (lambda in lambdas)
{
  performance <- rbind(performance,
                       data.frame(Lambda = lambda,
                                  RMSE = rmse(test.y,
                                              with(test.df,
                                                   predict(glmnet.fit,
                                                           poly(X, degree = 10),
                                                           s = lambda)))))
}
```

what does the parameter 's' in this case mean?Could't find it in the help file.

Comment: Please list the non-base R packages that you are using. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: This seems like the correct documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.1-1/topics/predict.cv.glmnet

Answer (score 1):

To find the documentation of the `predict` function for different objects, you can usually use `?predict.objectName`. So for instance, to find the documentation for the `predict` function for `lm` objects, you'd use `?predict.lm`.

In this case, you have a `glmnet` object, and you can use `?predict.glmnet` to [find the relevant documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/1.1-1/topics/predict.glmnet), which describes `s` as follows:

- `s` - Value(s) of the penalty parameter lambda at which predictions are required. Default is the entire sequence used to create the model.